# How add data in list using method in C# ? i am trying to add but it cannot hold data and just display the last entry

Tags: c#

This is my problem . For solving i use list in method but it just display the last entry. and hold previous data. please solve

Question >
There is a book library. Define classes respectively for a book and a library. The library must contain a name and a list of books. The books must contain the title, author, publisher, release date and ISBN-number. In the class, which describes the library, create methods to add a book to the library, to search for a book by a predefined author, to display information about a book and to delete a book from the library.  Write a test class, which creates an object of type library, adds several books to it and displays information about each of them. Implement a test functionality, which finds all books authored by Stephen King and deletes them. Finally, display information for each of the remaining books.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication310
{
    class book
    {
         public string title;
         public string author;
         public string publisher;
         public string releasedate;
         public string ISBN;
        public void display()
         {
             Console.WriteLine(title);
             Console.WriteLine(author);
             Console.WriteLine(publisher);
             Console.WriteLine(releasedate);
             Console.WriteLine(ISBN);
             Console.WriteLine("=======================");
         }
    }
    class liberay : book
    {
        string libname;
        public static List<book> b=new List<book>();
        public liberay(string libn)
        {
            libname = libn;
        }
        public void addbook(string t, string a, string p, string r, string i)
        {
            b = new List<book>()
            {
                new book{title=t,author=a,publisher=p,releasedate=r,ISBN=i}
            };
        }
        public void show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(libname);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Count; i++)
            {
                b[i].display();

            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            liberay obj = new liberay("name");

            obj.addbook("a", "a", "a", "a", "a");

            obj.addbook("b", "b", "b", "b", "b");
            obj.show();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of replacing your list of books when you call addbook(), using b.add(new book{title=t,author=a,publisher=p,releasedate=r,ISBN=i});

Comment: This is a good time to learn to use the debugger. Step through the code while it runs and it should be easy enough to understand what's wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I explained the answer, instead of REPLACING the list of books, ADD your book to it, then showed the example. I think it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Jon thanks for help now its working

Comment: i cannot understand negative votes . it is not valid question ?

Comment: As I said, you have to be able to find the error by yourself simply by using the [Step Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019). This is the first step to do when you don't understand why something happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

When you call the addbook method, the list variable is initialized. So it always points to the last object.

For this reason, it only points to the last book you added.

```
    public void addbook(string t, string a, string p, string r, string i)
    {

        b = new List<book>()
        {
            new book{title=t,author=a,publisher=p,releasedate=r,ISBN=i}
        };
    }
```

->

```
    public void addbook(string t, string a, string p, string r, string i)
    {  
        b.Add(new book { title = t, author = a, publisher = p, releasedate = r, ISBN = i });
    }
```

remove method

```
    public void RemoveBookFromISBN(string targetISBN)
    {
        var target = b.Find((x) => x.ISBN == targetISBN);

        if(target != null)
            b.Remove(target); 
    }
```

Comment: Bro what should i do if i want remove this data in method just by add data by enter ISBN number

Comment: add RemoveBookFromISBN